# what is the meaning of this proposition?

Tags: complex-analysis

Prop: The image of an entire nonconstant functions misses at most one point of $\mathbb{C}$

What is the meaning of missing a point of $\mathbb{C}$? Does it mean that $f(z) = 0$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C} $?

Comment: $w$ is missed if there  is no $z$ such that $f(z)=w$.

Answer (score 1):

It means there is at most one point not in the range of the function,  i.e,  for at most one $z\in \mathbb C$,  for no $y\in \mathbb C$ does $f(y)=z$

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is at most one $y\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)\neq y$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$

Answer (score 0):

$w=e^z$ is a good example which is entire and misses the $0$ in $w-$plane as $e^z\not=0$.